# Создание типа РПГ на Java

Tags: java, наследование

Тут уже был похожий вопрос, но там тишина.
Условие такое:
Герой игры обладает никнеймом, силой, ловкостью и интеллектом, помимо этого у него есть здоровье, мана и опыт и позиция на карте в координатах х, у. Любой герой может переместиться за курсором, атаковать, защищаться, выполнить действие. Герой может принадлежать любому из 3 классов - маг, воин, лучник.

При создании персонажа у пользователя есть выбор класса.

Помимо базовых характеристик героя, у классов есть свои особенности:

Маг имеет больший запас маны при создании и способен атаковать на расстоянии. Маг имеет возможность произносить заклинания из списка. Маг имеет возможность изучать заклинания в случае нахождения свитка соответствующего заклинания.

Воин имеет больший запас здоровья при создании, больший урон с руки, возможность атаковать при помощи предмета.

Лучник - имеет лук при создании и способен атаковать на расстоянии. Лучник имеет возможность избежать урон при атаке и умеет открывать любые замки. Необходимо описать недостающие методы и добавить часть кода для того, чтобы программа заработала.

Механика метода attack - герой всегда наносит удар первым, потом ждет удара от цели и так до гибели кого либо из атакующих. В случае убийства цели (здоровье цели упало до 0 или ниже) - цель удар не наносит. В этом случае герой приобретает опыт цели. Каждые 500 единиц опыта герой получает новый уровень и это влияет на его характеристике в соответствии с описанием ниже. Если цель убивает героя необходимо вывести в консоль "Ваш герой был убит".

```
class Item {
    int price, weight, type;
    public Item(int price, int weight, int type){
        this.price = price;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
class Enemy{
    int hp, damage;
    int exp;
    public Enemy(int hp, int damage, int exp){
        this.hp = hp;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.exp = exp;
    }
}
abstract class Hero{
    protected String nickName;
    protected int s, a, i, exp, hp, mana; // сила ловкость интеллект 
опыт здоровье мана
    protected int x, y; // координаты героя на карте
    protected ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>(); // список поднятых предметов
    protected int damage; // урон

    public int getMana(){
        return mana;
    }
    public int getDamage(){
        return damage;
    }
    public int getHp(){
        return hp;
    }
    public void goToCursor(int xx, int yy){
        x = xx; y = yy;
    }
    public abstract void attack(Enemy enemy); // этот метод должнен быть определен в классах наследниках

    public abstract void defense(Enemy enemy);// этот метод должнен быть определен в классах наследниках

    public void openItem(Item item){
        // метод должен добавлять предмет в список с вероятностью 50 %
        // для осуществления вероятностных процессов можно использовать случайное число от 0 до 100.
    }
}

class Warrior{
    public Warrior(){
        //базовые значение
    }
     /*
класс должен обладать всеми свойствами героя при создании воин должен 
обладать следующими характеристиками:
 здоровье - 500, мана - 10, сила - 100, ловкость - 50, интеллект - 1, 
опыт 0, урон - 150. При атаке герой наносит цели урон и получает урон в 
ответ от цели, действия повторяются пока кто то не победит. В случае 
победы герой получает опыт цели, каждые 500 единиц опыта герой получает 
новый уровень. Новый уровень дает +10 ко всем характеристикам, +200 
здоровья и +20 урона.Если воин имеет предмет 1 типа, к его урону 
добавляется 100.
    Уже мертвая цель - урона герою не наносит!!!
    */
}

class Archer{
    public Archer(){
        //базовые значение
    }
     /*
        класс должен обладать всеми свойствами героя при создании лучник должен обладать следующими характеристиками: здоровье - 200, мана - 50, сила - 20, ловкость - 150, интеллект - 30, опыт 0, урон - 200.
    атака по аналогии с воином, но в процессе атаки лучник имеет 30% шанс избежать урон
    лучник всегда открывает предмет - 100%
    Новый уровень дает +10 ко всем характеристикам, +50 здоровья и +50 урона и 30 ловкости.
    */
}
class Magician{
    public Magician(){
        //базовые значение
    }
    private ArrayList<Item> casts = new ArrayList<>();
/*
к

ласс должен обладать всеми свойствами героя при создании маг должен обладать следующими характеристиками: здоровье - 100, мана - 5000, сила - 5, ловкость - 30, интеллект - 300, опыт 0, урон - 40.атака по аналогии с воиномпомимо обычной атаки, маг имеет возможность бить заклинанием в процессе атаки
защита мага осуществляется магическим щитом, который полгащает весь урон, но вместо здоровья тратит ману. Новый уровень дает +10 ко всем характеристикам, +30 здоровья, 1000 маны и +10 урона.
В случае возможности убить врага с руки - маг бьет с руки!!! в Первую очередь
*/

public void makeCast(Enemy enemy){
            // если в списке есть заклятия можно его произнести потратив 100 маны и нанеся 1000 урона цели.
    // после произнесения предмет из списка пропадает
        }
        public void eduCast(Item item){
                    /*
            если предмет или предметы из списка имеют тип 2, это заклинания 
    и их нужно добавить в список
    заклинаний мага
            */
        }

    }
```

Main для тестирования примерно такой:

```
public class TestClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Hero myHero = new Warrior();
            // Hero myHero = new Archer();
            // Hero myHero = new Magician();

            ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();
            enemies.add(new Enemy(30, 20, 1200)); // 1 - Крестьянин
            enemies.add(new Enemy(2018, 1, 350)); // 2 - Стая собак
            enemies.add(new Enemy(280, 50, 3050)); // 3 - Вор
            enemies.add(new Enemy(100500, 100500, 100500)); // 4 - 
    Берсерк

            //найден клад
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
                Item item = new Item(0, 0, i % 3); // i%3 - будет задавать 
    предмету тип 0, 1, 2
                myHero.openItem(item);  // герои получает предмет в руки
            }
            System.out.println("Всего собрано: " + myHero.items.size());

            // бой!
            int count = 1;
            for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {
                System.out.println(count++ + "-й бой:");
                System.out.println("  Герои { hp=" + myHero.hp + " mana=" + 
    myHero.mana + " }");
                System.out.println("  Враг { hp=" + enemy.hp + " }");
                int counter = 1;
                while (myHero.hp > 0 & enemy.hp > 0) {
                    System.out.println(counter++ + " раунд:");
                    myHero.attack(enemy);
                    myHero.defense(enemy);
                    System.out.println("    Герои { hp=" + myHero.hp + " 
    mana=" + myHero.mana + " }");
                    System.out.println("    Враг { hp=" + enemy.hp + " }");
                }
                System.out.println(myHero.hp > 0 ? "Победа, герой получил 
    опыт " + enemy.exp : "Поражение");
                System.out.printf("Герой { HP=%d, MANNA=%d, damage=%d, 
    exp=%d }\n", myHero.hp, myHero.mana, myHero.damage, myHero.exp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Главный затык у меня сейчас с классом Warrior. Никак не могу сделать так чтобы предмет типа 1 увеличивал атаку на 100 только один раз. получается что он каждый раз увеличивает атаку когда встречаетв  цикле премет типа 1. 
В класс Hero я добавил следующие методы:

```
 public void openItem(Item item) { //добавляет итем в инвентарь
        int c = 0;
        double d = Math.random();
        if (d > 0.5) {
            items.add(item);
        }
        whatStuffIs(item);
    }

    public void whatStuffIs(Item item) { // определяет тип итема и совершает определенное действие

    }
```

Класс **Warrior**:

```
class Warrior extends Hero { 
    public Warrior() { //задаем начальные характеристики при создании персонажа
        this.hp = 500;
        this.mana = 10;
        this.s = 100;
        this.a = 50;
        this.i = 1;
        this.exp = 0;
        this.damage = 150;

    }


    @Override
    public void whatStuffIs(Item item) { //определяем тип предмета, если 1 то увеличиваем урон на 100
        for (Item item1 : items) {
            if (item1.type == 1) {
                damage +=100;
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void attack(Enemy enemy) { //атака героя 

        if (hp > 0 && enemy.hp > 0) {
            enemy.hp -= damage;
        }
        if (enemy.hp < 0) {
            newLevel(enemy.exp);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void defense(Enemy enemy) { //атака противника
        if (enemy.hp > 0) {
            hp -= enemy.damage;
        }
        if (hp < 0) System.out.println("Ваш герой убит!");
    }


    @Override
    public void newLevel(int exp1) {  //увеличение уровня и характеристик
        int n = (exp % 500 + exp1) / 500;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            hp += 200;
            damage += 20;
            s += 10;
            i += 10;
            a += 10;
            mana += 10;

        }
        exp += exp1;
    }

}
```

буду очень признателен, если поможете разобраться.

Comment: `Никак не могу сделать так чтобы предмет типа 1 увеличивал атаку на 100 только один раз`. Создайте поле, которое будет хранить состояние того, что уже увеличивалась сила атаки на 100. При следующих атаках проверяйте это состояние.

Comment: Сделайте break в цикле. после увеличения :)

Comment: Пробовал. Не помогло)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конце концов сделал так.
В классе **Warrior**:

```
 @Override
    public void openItem(Item item) {

            items.add(item);
            whatStuffIs(item);
        }


    public void whatStuffIs(Item item) {
        if (item.type==1 && !isDamageGrow()) damage += 100;
    }


    public boolean isDamageGrow(){
        return damage>=250 ?  true: false;
    }
```